# Jackson serialization/deserialization problems when using @JsonTypeInfo. Can someone explain to me how this is working?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, annotations

Say I have these classes

```
public abstract class Shape {}

public class Circle extends Shape{
    private int r;
    ...
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
         String json = "{\"r\": 25 }";
         ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

         //WORKS FINE
         Circle circle = om.readValue(json, Circle.class); 
    }
}
```

Now, say I want to add another class that will contain a list of *Shape* objects. I understand that to deserialize this class, I will have to add @JsonTypeInfo.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Circle.class, name = "circle")
})
public abstract class Shape {}

public class Circle extends Shape{...}

public class ListOfShapes {
    List<Shape> shapes;
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
         String json = "{\"r\": 25 }";
         ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

         //DOES NOT WORK
         Circle circle = om.readValue(json, Circle.class); 
    }
}
```

I am able to successfully serialize the *ListOfShapes* object now using these annotations but I am no longer able to serialize the circle class. I also noticed that the json schema changed a bit when I serialized the class so I now have an extra key ("type"):

```
{
    "type": "circle",
    "r": 5
}
```

The work around for me at the moment is to change the json string a bit by adding that new key value pair:

```
String json = "{\"type\": \"circle\", \"r\": 25 }";
```

**Can someone explain to me whats going on here?**
**Why am I not able to serialize the circle object any more?**
**Why does the json schema change, by the addition of a new key value pair?**

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working as expected. When you add the `JsonTypeInfo` and `JsonSubTypes` annotations to your `Shape` class like you have done below:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Circle.class, name = "circle")
})
public abstract class Shape {}
```

You are informing jackson you are expecting to find a property named `type` in every json you want to deserialize to the `Shape` class and in case of absence jackson will raise an error, moreover the `type` property will be serialized with its value. You are also informing jackson that in case the value associated to the `type` property is *circle* the json has to be deserialized as a `Circle` object.

This behaviour is particularly useful when you are not aware of which type of object has to be deserialized or serialized like the example below :

```
String json = "{\"type\": \"circle\", \"r\": 25 }";
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
//I don't know json is a circle object but it can be deserialized as a Shape
Shape circle = om.readValue(json, Shape.class);
System.out.println(circle instanceof Circle); //<-- it prints true
//ok type is present with value circle {"type":"circle","r":25}
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(circle));
```

Same approach is used with a `ListOfShapes` wrapper class:

```
String json = "{\"type\": \"circle\", \"r\": 25 }";
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
Shape circle = om.readValue(json, Shape.class);
//instantiate the wrapper class
ListOfShapes listOfShapes = new ListOfShapes();
listOfShapes.shapes = List.of(circle);
json = mapper.writeValueAsString(listOfShapes);
//it prints {"shapes":[{"type":"circle","r":25}]}
System.out.println(json);
listOfShapes = om.readValue(json, ListOfShapes.class);
//ok list inside contains the Circle object
System.out.println(listOfShapes);
```